# Debian wifi phantom faliure

Tags: linux, debian

I have recently installed debian in a dual boot. The wi-fi in configurations displays the following message "No wifi adapter found, make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged and turned on". However, paradoxically, i am sending this using the "Debian half" of my pc. I have configured to the wifi connection during the debian installation process. Using

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:cd:5b:3d:37:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I get this messages, which haven't helped me a lot. I tried downloading iwlwifi and unpacking manually, but this changed nothing.
If someone could help me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Debian are you using? And how exactly have you installed the modules?

I would suggest following instructions from the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi#Troubleshooting), as this is quite known to occur and has been solved since:

> Troubleshooting
>
> My Wifi card doesn't work/is not detected: many Wifi network
> interfaces require proprietary Firmware to function. For these cards
> to work, you will need to either install Debian from the unofficial CD
> image with included non-free firmwares, or edit your package sources
> to include the non-free section, and install the
> firmware-linux-nonfree package (and/or other firmware-* packages).